# How to get the value from a form in php

Tags: php

```
<? 
   if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
   {
       $_SESSION['update'] = trim($_POST("wasUpdateClicked")_;
   }
   $wasUpdatedClicked = $_SESSION['wasUpdatedClicked'];
   if(isset($wasUpdateClicked))
   {
      ..do something here like an update method
   }
?>
<form name="x" method="post" action="samePage.php">
      ...do some stuff here that isnt important
   <input type="submit" value="update" onclick="$wasUpdateClicked = 2" />
</form>
```

My beef is that I cant get the right value for the wasUpdateClicked variable. Is there any way to do this???? It seems that when my action is to the same page I can't get my variables. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [@alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31671/alex):

This is not how forms work. Only the content of form elements are sent to the server, identified by their `name`.

So this

```
<input type="submit" value="update" onclick="$wasUpdateClicked = 2" />
```

will just set the JavaScript variable `$wasUpdateClicked` to `2`. This happens only on the client side. The value is never sent to the server.

You would need a form element, like:

```
<input type="text" name="wasUpdateClicked" value="2" />
<!-- or type="hidden" -->
```

and maybe update this value with JavaScript. Or if you actually want to count the number of form submissions, you can count them on the server side using `$_SESSION` (just having a form element that always sends `2` seems kinda useless).

You should read about [*variables from external sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and describe what you actually want to do.

Comment: How would the form get submitted without a input type of submit?

Comment: @Zach You can submit a form many ways, including a `button` and using JavaScript.

Comment: @Zach: I'm not saying you should remove the submit button (you should remove this useless `click` handler though. What clicks do you actually want to track?

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` is a variable, not a function.

Subscript it like so...

```
$var = $_POST['wasUpdateClicked'];
```

Also, I usually find it easier to check for a POST like with `if ( ! empty($_POST)) { ... }`.

To use `$_SESSION`, you need to call `session_start()` first.

This line has a few issues...

```
<input type="submit" value="update" onclick="$wasUpdateClicked = 2" />
```

You can not do that with PHP. I think you are confusing JavaScript with PHP (still, that would be bad practice JavaScript).

Comment: I was getting it confused, and it makes perfect sense that i was able to see the variables since it was sent.

Answer (score 0):

You shall replace

```
 <input type="submit" value="update" onclick="$wasUpdateClicked = 2" />
```

by

```
<input type="hidden" name="wasUpdateClicked" value="2"/>  
<input type="submit" value="update"/>
```

and at the beg. of your script, get the posted value with

```
$wasUpdatedClicked = $_POST['wasUpdateClicked'];
```

Comment: Great, then pls don't forget to vote as this is a recognition way. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here are some pointers which should help.

If you assign a name to a button, its value will be part of the $_POST array.

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></input>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
```

Depending on which button they clicked, `$_POST['submit']` will be "update" or "submit".

Another way to do this is to set a hidden input's value in the onclick function.

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="">
<input type="submit" value="update" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value = 'update'" />
```

Then, `$_POST['action']` will be "update" if they clicked the update button.

To do the update if they clicked the update button, do something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'update')
{
    // do your update
}
```